# word vba loop do if find.found

Tags: vba, ms-word, do-while

I'm trying to use Word VBA to loop through a document and what I'm trying to do is, if I find `.Text = "A" & vbTab`, then I want to replace it with `"A: "`, then go to the end of the line, press the DEL key once and type `<br>`. But I couldn't manage it, somehow word keeps crashing when I run this code..

```
Sub marx()
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveDocument.Range

r.Find.ClearFormatting
With r.Find
    .Text = "A" & vbTab
    .Replacement.Text = "A: "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
End With

Do While r.Find.Found

Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:="<br>"
r.Find.Execute
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably crashing because the code goes into an infinite loop - because Find keeps executing and, since you don't *replace* the found term it keeps finding the same search term over and over again.

Even if that weren't happening and you did do a Replace, the result wouldn't be what you expect because the Selection would still be what it was when you started the macro.

First, you need to execute a Replace and secondly, you need to Select the found Range (and in order to go to the end of a line you do need Selection). Lastly, the loop needs only one Find.Execute.

Here's one way to successfully approach your problem. Note that I use a boolean to pick up whether the search was successful and test that, both for the Do loop as well as for whether the Selection actions should be performed.

Note also the `Replace` argument in `Find.Execute` - just setting `Replacement.Text` isn't enough.

And look at how I use `r.Select` before the Selection actions.

```
Sub marx()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    bFound = True
    Set r = ActiveDocument.content

    r.Find.ClearFormatting
    Do While bFound
        With r.Find
            .Text = "A" & vbTab
            .Replacement.Text = "A: "
            .Forward = True
            .wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            bFound = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
        End With

        If bFound Then
            r.Select
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.TypeText Text:="<br>"
        End If
    Loop    
End Sub
```