# Capitalise the second character in a string while finding and replacing?

Tags: vba, ms-word

extreme VBA noob here. I'm trying to write a macro that searches for every tab and the letter following it, and replaces it with a tab and that capitalised letter.

I've figured out the following using internet articles around the place, but I'm not sure how to correctly write the Replacement.Text line.  Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Capitaliser()
    With Selection.Find
        Text = "^t?"
        Replacement.Text = UCase(Text)
        Forward = True
        Wrap = wdFindContinue
        Format = False
        MatchCase = False
        MatchWholeWord = False
        MatchWildcards = True
        MatchSoundsLike = False
        MatchAllWordForms = False
        Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think `wdReplaceAll` is going to work with dynamic replacement text - I''m pretty sure you'll need to loop through result by result. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392210/4088852) might be a good starting point.

Comment: What is your code doing/not doing? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @ashleedawg The code doesn't give an error, but it deletes all text that applies to "t^?".

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for the link, i'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^t[a-z]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Text = UCase(.Text)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```