# Insert image into Word document in the line below the found text

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am creating an automated document generation tool using data from an Excel workbook through VBA code.

The code below replaces text and inserts the images, however, they get pushed into the top of the document.

Is there any way to return the position of the found text, declare a range based on the position, and use that to insert the inline-shape (image) into the line after the tagName text?

I had this working previously through calling Word macros from Excel, however, this needs to be completely Excel based.
This program will be handling Word documents that have no VBA.

```
For Each sr2 In wDoc.StoryRanges
    With sr2.Find
        .Text = tagName
        .Replacement.Text = tagValue
        .Wrap = 1
        .Execute Replace:=2
        If .Found = True Then
            sr2.InlineShapes.AddPicture fileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\1. SOW Templates\ Client Summary import.jpg"
        End If
    End With
Next sr2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To easily loop through the results of the Find method, it would be easier if you are using `Replace:=wdReplaceOne` (wdReplaceOne=1) instead of `Replace:=wdReplaceAll` (wdReplaceAll=2). (Based on this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392210/5958842)).

To insert the image, I would suggest you to select the range you want the image to be. Add it as a free floating image and then convert it to an inline shape.

Here's a way to do this:

```
Dim r As Object 'Word.Range
Dim bFound As Boolean

bFound = True
Set r = wDoc.Content

r.Find.ClearFormatting
Do While bFound
    With r.Find
        .Text = tagname
        .Replacement.Text = tagValue
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        bFound = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
    End With

    If bFound Then
        r.Select
        Selection.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Select
        Dim img As Object 'Word.Shape
        Set img = wDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\1. SOW Templates\ Client Summary import.jpg")
        img.ConvertToInlineShape
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for, works great. I was working with inserting 10+images at a time so i just removed the do while statement and it worked like a charm. Is there a way for me insert onto the second instance of my tagName? Many times I have a table of contents in the document and would like to skip over it so i do not corrupt the formatting of the table.
Thanks for all the help @DecimalTurn

Comment: I'm glad this answer was helpful. Regarding your question, I'm not sure I understand it correctly. Moreover, since this seems like a separate question, it would be better to post it as another question.